# New column every time i run script

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

i have a problem.
I want to make a bash script that writes data to new column every time i run script.
For example every week i check how many files in each folder i have.

```
find /home/user/admin/stuff/ -mtime -7 | wc -l >> results.xls

find /home/user/admin/old/ -mtime -7 | wc -l >> results.xls
```

I run script every Monday, but i don't want to overwrite data. I need that new data will be in new column.

For example:

```
Week1 Week2 Week3 ...
  2     3     5
  1     2     3
```

Comment: im sorry in a new column :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

output_file=/tmp/results.xls

[ ! -f ${output_file} ] && echo -e "\n\n\n" > ${output_file}
stuff_count=$(find /home/user/admin/stuff/ -mtime -7 | wc -l)
old_count=$(find /home/user/admin/old/ -mtime -7 | wc -l)
now=$(date +%y%m%d)

sed -i "1 s/$/\t$now/" /tmp/out.txt
sed -i "2 s/$/\t$stuff_count/" /tmp/out.txt
sed -i "3 s/$/\t$old_count/" /tmp/out.txt
```

Comment: Sed is somehow hard to use when it would come to combine more lines. I would suggest `paste`. Something like `paste results.xls <(date +%y%m%d; find /home/user/admin/stuff/ -mtime -7 | wc -l; find /home/user/admin/old/ -mtime -7 | wc -l) > /tmp/tempresults; mv /tmp/tempresults results.xls`. Of course, in case of more complicated output, it could be prepared in some temporary file and then merged with `paste file_a file_b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a the output in this way.

```
week="" week=`date` echo $week >> results.xls 
find /home/user/admin/old/ -mtime -7 | wc -l >> results.xls

# cat results.xls
Thu Oct 27 14:16:29 IST 2016
0
2
```

This is just an example. You can modify it in your way.

Comment: i'm sorry i mean in a new column